# Wrapfigure formatting forces underful \hbox, except when I deliberately cause an error with empty $$

Tags: layout, wrapfig

This is a problem I've run into with the wrapfig package while using `\\` to skip a line. In the MWE below, the output is the one shown on the left, where the first paragraph has broken formatting that forces underfull `\hbox` on every line. However, when I insert an empty `$$` just before the `\\`, it raises an error but also makes the output the one shown on the right, which is what I want to have. I tried to be cheeky and use `$ $` instead, which does not raise an error, but then the output is again the image shown on the left. Ideally there'd be something that gives the output on the right in a more natural way.[image]

MWE below (note the comment that indicates where placing $$ fixes the output layout):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}{5.1cm}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Square vortex lattice}
\label{fig:square_lattice}
\end{wrapfigure} 

Nowadays, the structure of superconductors can be measured experimentally, and lattice structures have indeed been found. This lattice structure is what distinguishes type-II from type-I superconductors: for certain ranges of magnetic field strength, the magnetic field penetrates into the superconductor, resulting in a lattice of flux vortices such as the one shown in figure \ref{fig:square_lattice}. It can be calculated that a triangular lattice results in a slightly lower value of $\beta_A = 1.16$. Indeed, the triangular lattice minimises the total energy of the system, although the difference is small enough that environmental factors can still make the square lattice favourable in real materials\\%Adding $$ before \\ fixes layout somehow.

Although the magnetic field penetrates the superconductor within theses vortices, transport of current with zero resistance is still a possibility in this state. Type-II superconductors can generally keep their zero resistance property up to fields much stronger than those for type-I superconductors, and also have larger critical temperatures. For this reason, type-II superconductors have become prominent in a large variety of practical applications, where often zero resistance is the property of interest, rather than field expulsion. Type-II superconductors have made themselves the more common type, and most contemporary research involves type-II superconductors with exceptional critical temperatures or critical fields.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\` at the end of a paragraph is wrong. Use a space command like \medskip to get space between paragraphs (or if you want the space always change \parskip).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}{5.1cm}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Square vortex lattice}
\label{fig:square_lattice}
\end{wrapfigure}

Nowadays, the structure of superconductors can be measured experimentally, 
and lattice structures have indeed been found. This lattice structure is 
what distinguishes type-II from type-I superconductors: 
for certain ranges of magnetic field strength, the magnetic field penetrates into the 
superconductor, resulting in a lattice of flux vortices such as 
the one shown in figure \ref{fig:square_lattice}. It can be calculated that a 
triangular lattice results in a slightly lower value of $\beta_A = 1.16$.
 Indeed, the triangular lattice minimises the total energy of the system, 
 although the difference is small enough that environmental factors can still 
 make the square lattice favourable in real materials

\medskip
Although the magnetic field penetrates the superconductor within theses vortices, transport of current with zero resistance is still a possibility in this state. Type-II superconductors can generally keep their zero resistance property up to fields much stronger than those for type-I superconductors, and also have larger critical temperatures. For this reason, type-II superconductors have become prominent in a large variety of practical applications, where often zero resistance is the property of interest, rather than field expulsion. Type-II superconductors have made themselves the more common type, and most contemporary research involves type-II superconductors with exceptional critical temperatures or critical fields.
\end{document}
```